# Outputting an "unused" XML namespace using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using Python 3.2's `xml.etree.ElementTree`, and am attempting to generate XML like this:

```
<XnaContent xmlns:data="Model.Data">
    <Asset Type="data:MyData">
        ...
```

The format is out of my control (it's XNA). Notice that the `data` XML namespace is never actually used to qualify elements or attributes, but rather to qualify attribute values to XNA. My code looks like this:

```
root = Element('XnaContent')
ET.register_namespace('data', 'Model.Data') 
asset = SubElement(root, 'Asset', {"Type": "data:MyData"})
```

However, the output looks like (pretty-printed by me):

```
<XnaContent>
    <Asset Type="data:MyData">
        ...
    </Asset>
</XnaContent>
```

How can I get the `data` XML namespace included in the output?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>print ET.tostring(doc, pretty_print=True)
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="data:MyData"/>
  <Asset Type="data:MyData"/>
</XnaContent>
>>> tree=ET.ElementTree(doc)
>>> root=tree.getroot()
>>> nsmap=root.nsmap
>>> nsmap['data']="ModelData"
>>> new_root = ET.Element(root.tag, nsmap=nsmap)
>>> print ET.tostring(new_root, pretty_print=True)
<XnaContent xmlns:data="ModelData"/>
>>> new_root[:] = root[:]
>>> print ET.tostring(new_root, pretty_print=True)
<XnaContent xmlns:data="ModelData">
  <Asset Type="data:MyData"/>
  <Asset Type="data:MyData"/>
</XnaContent>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get: `AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'nsmap'`, nor is `nsmap` mentioned [here](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: @unutbu: correct, but I am not and cannot - it's not available in my Python environment.

Comment: @unutbu is right, I am using lxml, i only briefly looked at your code and presumed that so were you. Hope you will find an answer for xml.etree. but i am afraid, it might be a problematic.

Answer (score 1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
content = '''
<XnaContent>
  <Asset Type="data:MyData"/>
  <Asset Type="data:MyData"/>
</XnaContent>'''
doc = ET.fromstring(content)
ET.register_namespace('data','ModelData')
tree = ET.ElementTree(doc)
root = tree.getroot()
root.tag = '{ModelData}XnaContent'
print(ET.tostring(root, method = 'xml'))
```

yields

```
<data:XnaContent xmlns:data="ModelData">
      <Asset Type="data:MyData" />
      <Asset Type="data:MyData" />
    </data:XnaContent>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. You've put `XnaContent` in the `data` namespace, but it isn't supposed to be.