# Python Element Tree: Namespace location is changed when writing the XML file back

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to parse a XML file, modify some values, and write the file back using the python code below. When writing the file back, it changes the namespace declaration location from `assemblyBinding` element to `root` (configuration) element. Due to this I am having other issues when that XML file is consumed.  Is it possible to maintain the location of namespace declaration?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ET.register_namespace('', "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")

tree = ET.parse('abc.xml')
root = tree.getroot()       
..
tree.write('abc.xml')
```

**Original Configuration**

```
<configuration>      
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">         
        <assemblyIdentity culture="neutral"/>                  
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Modified Configuration**

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">      
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding>          
        <assemblyIdentity culture="neutral"/>               
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I am using Python 3.7
Thank you.

Comment: Does the consuming application care if a prefix is used? If you add a prefix to the `register_namespace` (like `ET.register_namespace('asm', "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1")`), there's now a prefix but the actual namespaces are correct in the output. If the consuming application handles XML correctly, the prefix shouldn't matter; only the namespace uri is important. Great question btw. +1

Comment: There is not much you can do about this (apart from switching to lxml). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45990761/407651

Comment: @DanielHaley: Thanks Daniel. I tried that earlier, but doesn't help, and that's why I deduced that it's not the namespace resolution, but namespace location which is causing the issue. I believe I may have to go with mzjn's suggested approach.

Comment: @mzjn: Using lxml resolved the issue. Thank you.