# Python ElementTree parse and write as original format

Tags: python, elementtree

So I'm trying to parse an xml file, and replace a tag value. I'm able to do this fine with tree.find(). However, the issue comes when I then write the data to a new xml file. The new xml file has the replaced value that I added, but a bunch of other stuff in the xml seems to be changed as well, in terms of formatting. It completely removed my first line of

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"...>

and changed a lot of the namespaces. I'm wondering what I can do to just leave everything else of my original xml, but just replace that one value.

Thanks

Comment: show some code and data file

Comment: Interesting, will you be using the [xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) module?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45990761/407651