# After Parsing XML , two of the namespaces are missing even after registering the namespace

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to parse the XML and write it to a file. When I try to do it, some of the namespaces is not seen when I write to file.

Below is the code which I have written to parse the XML

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:PT xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1" xmlns:ns0000="http://schemas/2006/1" xmlns:"ps"= "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08">
</p:PT
```

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse("1.xml")

root = tree.getroot()
ET.ElementPath._cache.clear()
namespaces = {"p": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/",
                  "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
                  "xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
                  "ns0000": "http://schemas/2006/1",
                  "ps": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08"}


for prefix,uri in namespaces.items():
    try:
        ET.register_namespace(prefix,uri)
    except:
        ET._namespace_map[uri] = prefix



tree.write("a.xml",  xml_declaration = True, encoding="UTF-8")
```

in the output XML, we are NOT seeing

```
"xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
"ns0000": "http://schemas/2006/1",
"ps": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/08"
```

Below is the output XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<p:PT xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2003/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1">
</p:PT>
```

Can you please help me over this

Comment: ElementTree removes declarations for namespaces that are not used. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45990761/407651.

Comment: @mzjn is there any way in elementTree to achieve this.

Comment: If you can, use lxml.