# Python - keep output XML namespace definitions at non-root nodes with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I want to generate an output XML from a modified input XML in Python using *xml.etree.ElementTree*  (short: *ElementTree*). The input XML has multiple namespaces and the output XML should also have these namespaces, **defined at the same nodes as the input XML**; the latter is important for specific reasons. However, *ElementTree* by default sets the namespaces at the root node. How can I prevent this if possible? Below is a minimal example (without modifications to the input XML):

**Read + write the XML (*demo_input_xml.py*):**

```
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

infile = sys.argv[1]
outfile = sys.argv[2]

# read the input XML file
tree = ET.parse(infile)
# get the tree root
root = tree.getroot()

# insert modifications to XML here

# open the output file and write out the new XML tree
ofile = open(outfile, 'w')
tree.write(ofile)
ofile.close()
```

**Input XML (*demo_temp_input.xml*):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tag0 xmlns="namespace0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation0">
  <tag1a>someText</tag1a>
  <tag1b xmlns="namespace1" xmlns:n1="namespace2" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation1">
    <tag2>
      <tag3 xmlns="namespace3" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation2">
      </tag3>
    </tag2>
  </tag1b>
</tag0>
```

**Actual output XML (*demo_temp_output.xml*):**

```
<ns0:tag0 xmlns:ns0="namespace0" xmlns:ns2="namespace1" xmlns:ns3="namespace3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation0">
  <ns0:tag1a>someText</ns0:tag1a>
  <ns2:tag1b xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation1">
    <ns2:tag2>
      <ns3:tag3 xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation2">
      </ns3:tag3>
    </ns2:tag2>
  </ns2:tag1b>
</ns0:tag0>
```

**Desired output XML:**

```
<ns0:tag0 xmlns:ns0="namespace0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation0">
  <ns0:tag1a>someText</ns0:tag1a>
  <ns2:tag1b xmlns:ns2="namespace1" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation1">
    <ns2:tag2>
      <ns3:tag3 xmlns:ns3="namespace3" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocation2">
      </ns3:tag3>
    </ns2:tag2>
  </ns2:tag1b>
</ns0:tag0>
```

Things to consider:

- The python version used is 2.7.18.
- The *lxml* package is not available and I do not have permissions to install it.
- The input XML has multiple default namespaces (i.e. no prefixes). Ideally, the output XML would also have multiple default namespaces (I already played around with *ET.register_namespaces()* and *ET._namespace_map*, without success), but this is not a priority. Thus, other namespace prefixes, also ones generated by *ElementTree*, e.g. *ns0*, *ns2* etc., are in principle ok (side question: why is the prefix ***ns1*** not used by *ElementTree*?).
- *ElementTree* does not store unused namespaces (in the minimal example the prefix *n1*, *"namespace2"*). Once any tag below that namespace uses the prefix in the input XML, *ElementTree* puts such namespaces with the (input) prefixes at the root node in the output XML. I had expected the default behavior would be to keep any namespaces no matter whether they are later used or not, but this is fine.
- *ElementTree* omits the XML version header line from the input XML; this is fine.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to prevent ElementTree from moving all namespace declarations to the root element. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45990761/407651.

Comment: @mzjn: Not that good news, but thanks in any case for the info. Would it maybe be possible with *lxml*  (if I was allowed to install it) or is the behavior the same? If the latter, a post-processing may probably be unavoidable.

Comment: Yes, using lxml is an option (it is mentioned in the answer to the linked question).

Comment: Alright, I'll check if I can gain permissions to install *lxml*. If so, I'll use that, else I may do some post-processing. Thanks once more for your help and also for the answer in the link :)