# preserve namespaces with xml.etree

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, elementtree

When namespaces are defined in the root element of a source file, `lxml` reproduces all of them in the output. I need to do this with `xml.etree`. Even better would be to only output those that are used, but `xml.etree` does not find all of them.

One solution is to add the namespaces forcibly with `root.set()`. However, this duplicates any namespaces that `xml.etree` does find, as shown below.

Complete example suitable for pasting in a command prompt:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
try:
    from io import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO

def get_namespaces(sourcestring):
    sourcefile = StringIO(sourcestring)
    return dict(
        [node for _, node in ET.iterparse(sourcefile, events=['start-ns'])])

ET._namespace_map = dict()  # remove any previously registered namespaces
sourcetext = (
    '<desc xmlns="uri_a" xmlns:b="uri_b" xmlns:c="uri_c"'
    ' b:foo="c:bar">a</desc>')
source = ET.fromstring(sourcetext)
namespaces = get_namespaces(sourcetext)
for prefix, uri in namespaces.items():
    ET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
    if prefix:
        tag = 'xmlns:' + prefix
    else:
        tag = 'xmlns'
    source.set(tag, uri)

print(ET.tostring(source, encoding='unicode'))
```

The result, which causes my application to fail:

```
<desc xmlns="uri_a" xmlns:b="uri_b" xmlns="uri_a" xmlns:b="uri_b" xmlns:c="uri_c" b:foo="c:bar">a</desc>
```

This is similar to [Forcing xml.etree to output "unused" namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557151/forcing-xml-etree-to-output-unused-namespaces), but the namespaces come from a source file so they are not known by the Python code.

Answer (score 0):

First, generate the output without adding the missing namespaces. Get the namespaces found from that output. Then, generate the final output by adding the namespaces that were not found.

```
def add_namespaces_not_found(root):
    result_with_namespaces_found = ET.tostring(root, encoding='unicode')
    namespaces_found = get_namespaces(result_with_namespaces_found)
    for prefix, uri in namespaces.items():
        if prefix not in namespaces_found:
            if prefix:
                tag = 'xmlns:' + prefix
            else:
                tag = 'xmlns'
            root.set(tag, uri)
```

Result:

```
<desc xmlns="uri_a" xmlns:b="uri_b" xmlns:c="uri_c" b:foo="c:bar">a</desc>
```

Solutions that do not require generating the output twice are welcome.